# WPF databinding How to create a TreeView with a root and bind its children to a list?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, treeview

For example if I have a List = {"A", "B", "C"}, I want the treeview to be

```
+Root
 -A
 -B
 -C
```

I tried

```
    <TreeView>
        <TreeViewItem Header ="Root">
            <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{Binding Path=List}"/>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
```

but the result is

```
+Root
 -                      (just an empty node)
  -A
  -B
  -C
```

which is not what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeViewItem Header ="Root" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=List}"/>
</TreeView>
```